# Get value from list_string instead of key

Tags: entities

I have this field created through baseFieldDefinition

```
$fields['type'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
        ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
        ->setLabel(t('Type'))
        ->setRequired(TRUE)
        ->setSettings([
            'allowed_values' => [
                'house'    => 'House',
                'business' => 'Company',
            ],
        ])
        ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
            'label' => 'visible',
            'type' => 'list_default',
            'weight' => 6,
        ])
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
            'type' => 'options_select',
            'weight' => 6,
        ])
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

But when i get the entity in php rest resource

```
$request = RequestEntity::load($id);

$request->get('type)->value
// Returns key 'business' instead of value 'Company'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried `$request->get('type')->getString();`?

Comment: that does not work it returns the same as ->value, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

I could make this work by changing

```
$request->get('type)->value
```

to

```
$request->house_type->getSetting('allowed_values')[$request->get('house_type')->value]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me (Drupal 9):

```
  $request->get('type')->view()[0]['#markup'];
```